# What is difference between DC current from dynamo and DC current from battery?

Tags: current, battery-charging, inverter

Dynamo generate DC current and battery also gives DC current. Here my question is when I use inverter, it worked with battery however doesn't work with same voltage of current from dynamo. Why? Battery gives like 12 volts and dynamo produce and supply 12 volts works same with 12 volts DC bulb, then why inverter doesn't work?

Comment: Please provide relevant datasheets (for dynamo, inverter, battery)

Comment: How many amps of current are you measuring from the battery to the inverter? Is the dynamo providing the same number of amps?

Comment: What was the measured voltage out of the battery? What was the measured current out of the battery? What was the measured voltage out of the dynamo? What is powering the dynamo? What is the current rating of the dynamo?

Comment: A 12V battery will provide a very stable, low-ripple DC source. On the other hand, your dynamo may have some significant ripple voltage that could be upsetting the inverter.

Comment: "Doesn't work" how?  Smoke pours out?  It just silently doesn't generate electricity?  The generator stalls?  Something else happens?

Answer (score 4):

1. The dynamo voltage isn't constant at 12VDC.  It will vary depending on how fast the rotor is turning.
2. The dynamo probably can't deliver as much current as the battery.  Inverters need a **lot** of current.  Inverters step up the voltage. If you step up to 120V and need 1A of current, your inverter will have to draw 10A of current at 12V.
3. Even if the dynamo can supply the needed steady current, it may not be able to supply the sudden burst of current needed when the inverter starts up.  Inverters tend to draw a lot of current in the first moment at start up.  If the dynamo can't supply it, the voltage will drop for a moment.  The inverter will probably then shut off.

Answer (score 0):

Given a fixed field voltage and a rotating armature, the dynamo will produce AC, with a commutator included to produce full-wave-rectified-by-the-commutator fluctuating DC.

Comment: "A dynamo is an electrical generator that creates direct current using a commutator... A small electrical generator built into the hub of a bicycle wheel to power lights is called a hub dynamo, although these are invariably AC devices,[citation needed] and are actually magnetos." - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo